# Windows phone building an application tutorial

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I apologize in advance for asking this on SO but I cant seem to find an answer anywhere else.

Is there a good tutorial for building non trivial app on windows phone (7 or 8) from start to finish.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial? It sounds as if you have a specific, unasked question.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I mean an app that will use/have the most common parts/functionalities like: database, isolated storage, some complex controls like panorama, getting async data from web, parsing JSON data, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as windows phone has many features you can follow the below link and choose your own Sample

[Windows Phone Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/)

[Sample App Demonstration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx)

It also depends on which language you want to code, although c# is popular among them.

Answer (score 1):

All information to start can be found at http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us

For example this first step-by-step tutorial
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)